# Doctrine/Symfony how to update entity with specific data from array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have looking around for too long with no luck. My situation is that i have a bit large table +60 columns which is represented in Doctrine Entity. Working on FosREST and what i want to achieve is that i want to send a JSON with specific data let's say for example

```
[phone] => new_phone
[name] => new_name
[id] => 1
```

while like i said the entity contains over 60 columns like address, picture, category, etc...

and the phone, name and id are not what I want to change every time but i want to change some columns each time.
So at some time i might want to update phone and name other time i want to change the category third time i want to change category and photo and address 
so is there anything like this ?

```
$entity->update($parameters);
```

where the $parameters are dynamically changed as explained before.
ps. i know that i can build a very long function with something like

```
if(isset($parameters['name']){
     $entity->setName($parameters['name']);
}
```

but with 60 ifs this just sounds idiotic anyone have any other approach ?
Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the ORM component is more trouble that it's worth.  If you frequently need to just update a few fields then consider dropping down to the DBAL connection and using sql.  On the other hand, 60 columns is a bit of a code smell so perhaps a different design should be considered.

Comment: @Cerad yeah i know its a bit smell but there is no way to do another design anyway the accepted answer solved the issue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If the parameters are named after the attributes (here with underscore annotations), you can do this

```
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector;
// ...

public function setParameters($params) {
    foreach ($params as $k => $p) {
        $key = Inflector::camelize($k);
        if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
            $this->$key = $p;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

2) Same thing with the setters

```
use Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector;
// ...

public function setParameters($params) {
    foreach ($params as $k => $p) {
        $key = Inflector::camelize($k);
        if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
            $this->{'set'.ucfirst($key)}($p); // ucfirst() is not required but I think it's cleaner
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

3) If its not the same name, you can do this :

```
public function setParameters($params) {
    foreach ($params as $k => $p) {
        switch $k {
            case 'phone':
                $this->phoneNumber = $p;
                break;
            // ...
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

EDIT : Best approach is number two but you should define a white-list or a black-list in order to avoid the user updating something you don't want him to.

Comment: its not because there is the _ and camelCase problem with them like phone_number and phoneNumber so the first one wont work as for the second one its just like building 60 ifs :/

Comment: and its not gonna work either ways cuz i will end up using $entity->setParam($param) not $entity->param = $param

Comment: For your first comment, I made an edit to camelize the key. For the second one, I don't understand what you mean. You want to use the setters and getters ?