# Modify multiple entities with one form (bulk edit)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, bulkupdate

I want to be able to submit a form that modifies multiple entities. Let's say I've got a `BulkeditFormType` to change the 'active' (Boolean) or 'organisation' (EntityType with App\Entity\Organisation) fields on multiple users at once.

This is my current solution (semi-pseudo-code):

```
public function bulkedit(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(BulkeditFormType::class, null, [
        //..options
    ]);

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        // fields '_token' and empty values are unset, not shown in this example
        $formData = $request->request->get($form->getName());

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $entityManager->getRepository(App\Entity\User::class);
        $entities = $repo->findBy([
            'id' => [1,2,3,4,5]
        ]);
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $form = $this->createForm(BulkeditFormType::class, $entity, [
                //..options
            ]);

            $clearMissing = false;
            $form->submit($formData, $clearMissing);
            $entityManager->persist($entity);
        }

        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('@User/User/bulkedit.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Note that I've tried to include only relevant parts of my code, so please consider this as pseudo-code, just to get an idea of my current implementation.

While this solution works, it creates a `Form` object for every entity. Editing 100 users will lead to a large amount of memory usage and many useless database queries.

How can I modify my code in such a way that only one form will be generated which can be re-used by all entities? I've tried to use `$form->setData()`, but I feel like there must be a better way. A `CollectionType` will create multiple subforms instead of multiple forms, so in this case it doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: You can use the [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html) which would handle that for you. It would handle like a single form but internally I think it might even create as many sub-forms as required. Still unless you actually have performance issues this might be a better solution than handle it manually. Doctrine will update only the changed entities anyway.

Comment: Traditionally you would use a [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html) for this sort of thing.  But trying to deal with 100 of anything is not going to very performant regardless of the approach used.  A custom solution not using Symfony forms might be best.  vstm beat me by 5 seconds!

Comment: A CollectionType will generate many (sub-)forms. In my case the same action should be applied to all entities, so generating multiple (sub)forms is not needed.

Comment: No.  CollectionTypes do not create multiple forms.  All just one big form.  If you don't want to use it then that is fine.  But I think you reduced your posted code to the point where it makes little sense.

Comment: It won't generate multiple forms, but in this case (saving multiple entities) submitting 100 forms doesn't differ that much from submitting one form with 100 collection children. Not enough to spend time refactoring it that way.

Comment: @Cerad What do you mean by 'a solution not using Symfony Forms'?

Comment: There is no particular reason you can't generate your own html and then pull the posted data directly from the request object.  That would probably eliminate quite a bit of overhead.  You can also use the Doctrine connection object to directly interact with the database and thus eliminate much of the ORM overhead.

Comment: There is no particular reason you can't get rid of the complete framework either, but the (or just mine?) whole idea of using a framework is to use it as much as possible, only custom code when needed ;). Symfony Forms can still generate the HTML, the performance bottle neck is within the saving part. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42763962/1405981), but I'm not sure that's the best way to go in my case.